# Importing img Url from MongoDB using Mongoose doesn't work

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose, ejs

I'm trying to import img url from my database (mongodb) using mongoose, and display it with EJS, my problem is that I always get undefined.

The data I get when using findById is "item" =

```
[ 
    { 
        _id: 5b809b2c74e2f54c20ae30da,
        brand: 'honda',
        model: 'cbr250r',
        price: 20000,
        amount: 20,
        img: 'https://news.maxabout.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/22.png',
        backImg: 'https://wallpapercave.com/wp/wp3065342.png',
        views: 1,
        desc: 'this is a bike description' 
    } 
]
```

and I'm trying getting my "backImg" using this path: "item[0].backImg". When I console.log it I get undefined. I also tried "item.backImg"

that's the route file which includes the function:

```
const router = require('express').Router();
const bodyParser=require('body-parser')
const urlencodedParser =bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:false})
router.use(bodyParser.json());
router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
const itemModel = require('../models/itemsModel')
const userModel = require('../models/userModel')

//items//
router.get('/:_id',(req,res)=>{
    console.log(req.params._id)
    let q = itemModel.find({_id:req.params._id})
    q.exec(function(err,item){
        if(err){
            console.log(err)
        } else {
            console.log(item)
            console.log(item[0].brand)
            console.log(item[0].backImg)
            console.log(item.backImg)
            res.render('./pages/items' , {item:item,user: req.user,} )
        }
    })
})

module.exports = router
```

Comment: please show your related client server code.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be like this

```
..... // previous code
itemModel.findOne({_id:req.params._id})
.then((item)=>{
    if(!item){
        console.log("No record found");
    }
    console.log(item)
    console.log(item.brand)
    console.log(item.backImg)
})
.catch(err=>{
    console.log("Error",err)
})
```

Here you can see I have used the findOne method of mongoose that will give only 1 result (single object) from database.Also check if `req.params._id` is not `undefined`.If you have any queries let me know.

Comment: hi when using FindOne it gives me just an object instad of object with in an arry as a  resulte wich is great , but still the "backImg" consloe logged as "undefined" :\,

Answer (score 0):

so its seems those field that was imported as undefiend werent added to the item schema so that was the problem